# how to make a for Loop in an array in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have been try this over and over again but got the same output. I would like to make a loop in an array of strings but the code only visits the first value. This is my code I've tried:

```
name = Environ("username")
user1= Array("name.name1", "name.name2")
user2= Array("name1.name1", "name1.name2")

For i = 0 To Size ' I used Size coz I will add more names
    If name = user1(i) Then
        MsgBox "User1"
    ElseIf name = user2(i) Then
        MsgBox "User2"
    Else
        errorLog
    End If
Next
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've provided an explicit declaration and starting value for `Size`, when it's used in a `for` loop, it will assume a variant numeric type with a value 0.

So you get `For i = 0 To 0`: i.e. the loop will iterate once.

Writing `Option Explicit` at the top of your module helps reduce bugs like this.

If you want to get the size of an array, use `LBound` and `UBound`.

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea. This really heps me :)

Comment: ,But my problem now is, what if it is not identified either of the two arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done to solve my problem.

```
name = Environ("username")
Dim found as Boolean
found = false
user1= Array("name.name1", "name.name2")
user2= Array("name1.name1", "name1.name2")

'to check for user2
For i = 0 To UBound(user1)
    If name = user1(i) Then
        MsgBox "User1"
        found = true
    End If
Next
'to check for user2
For i = 0 To UBound(user2)
    If name = user2(i) Then
        MsgBox "User2"
        found = true
    End If
Next

'Else if the username is not on the list, I have added a Boolean found.
if found = false then 
    MsgBox "Unidentified Access!"
end If
```

Thank you so much for all your guidance!

Comment: I'd prefer to see `For i = LBound(user1) to UBound(user1)`. In this way you don't hardcode the *base* of the arrays.